# List of tuple<double,double>. Comma instead of point in double values

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, tuples, number-formatting

The situation: I have a list of tuple, in which a tuple is added:

```
List<Tuple<double, double>> list = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
list .Add(new Tuple<double, double>(2.2, 6.6));
```

All seems to be ok. But... In Debugging mode, in the list of local vars I see next:

```
[0] {(2,2, 6,6)}    System.Tuple<double,double>
```

By the way, the backword action working good:

```
double t = list[0].Item1;
```

I got:

```
t   2.2 double
```

May be it's not a big problem, but it frustrates me.

Any ideas why so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the debugger shows numbers in your local (user) national format, so it shows them as 2,2 and 6,6 instead of 2.2 and 6.6 .

I know various work places that use English versions of OS and Visual Studio so not to have similar problems :-) This is clearly not necessary, because you can...

...change in the Control Panel (International Settings) the format of decimal numbers.

Comment: That's explain everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

That is because your local culture settings have the `,` as decimal separator. Whenever .NET tries to parse it to a `string`, it uses this to determine what separator to use.

You could change your regional / culture settings to English US. You will see the decimal separators are you'd expect them to be. If you don't want this, stop worrying about it.